Error starting next js development server

'NextJS\the-wild-oasis-website\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'W:\Projects\next\dist\bin\next'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

I am trying to start next js development server, but I'm getting this error when I run npm run dev. I am using next js 14 and node version 20.13.1.

Just to be sure, did you run npm install?

It already had node_modules folder so I did not. Should I install it?

check your package.json dependencies it might by defined latest available version, for today it - "20.12.12"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node?activeTab=versions
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "@types/node": "20.12.12"
  ...
 }

or it might be defined in package.json
devDependencies { }
